# Regex find-and-replace in vim: Adding .0 to numbers

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file which looks like below.

```
1   1  0  #  1 
6   1  0  #  2 
8   1  0  #  3 
10  1  0  #  4 
12  1  0  #  6
```

How can I add .0 to all numbers, except the numbers behind the #. I think this should not be too difficult to do with a regular expression, but my regex knowledge is too rusty..

Comment: What language are you using to do this? Regex syntax differs across certain languages.

Comment: vim (search and replace)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your numbers after the `#` don't have spaces after them, you can use:

```
:g/\([0-9]\+\) /s//\1.0 /g
```

The use of `()` creates groups which you can refer to as `\D` in the replacement text, where `D` is the position of the group within the search string. This will give you:

```
1.0   1.0  0.0  #  1
6.0   1.0  0.0  #  2
8.0   1.0  0.0  #  3
10.0  1.0  0.0  #  4
12.0  1.0  0.0  #  6
```

If they *do* have spaces after them (which yours seem to have), you'll get:

```
1.0   1.0  0.0  #  1.0
6.0   1.0  0.0  #  2.0
8.0   1.0  0.0  #  3.0
10.0  1.0  0.0  #  4.0
12.0  1.0  0.0  #  6.0
```

in which case you can then do:

```
:g/\.0\(  *\)$/s//\1/g
```

to fix it up.

Comment: s/\\([0-9]\+\\) /\1.0 /g is shorter

Answer (score 9):

With VIM:

```
:%s/\v(#.*)@<!\d+/&.0/g
```

Explanation: `\v` = very magic (see `help \v`), `@<!` Matches with zero width if the preceding atom does NOT match just before what follows (see `help \@<!`). The rest of the pattern replaces strings of 1 or more digits with the same string followed by `.0`.

Comment: This one is beautiful. One needs to admit that. You get a vote up from me.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's well formed, using `sed` this should work.

EDIT: Just to clarify, `vim` was not attached as a tag to this questions when i saw it.

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\+\) \+\([0-9]\+\) \+\([0-9]\+\)/\1.0 \2.0 \3.0/' file
```

Comment: Why the backslash before the + and ()?

Comment: Also I don't understand \1.0 \2.0 and \3.0 after the / could you explain it a bit?

Comment: It needs to be escaped. \1 \2 \3 are groupings. I simply add .0 those each one of those groups.

Comment: Yes just read it up again \1 \2 \3 are the references for the groups defined before..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also 
sed 's/[0-9]/&.0/g' | sed 's/.0[ ]*$//g'

First sed add .0 all numbers and second one removes the trailing .0